# Spark yarn-client mode Python version

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a python module with PySpark on yarn-client mode. The default python on my cluster is 2.6.6 and i would like to use python 3 which is installed under the path `$/apps/anaconda/4.3.1/3/bin/python3.6` on my cluster. When i run the Spark module via the below spark2-submit it fails stating the wrong version of Python is being used. When i run the same code in cluster model with yarn-cluster, it succeeds. My question: how do i fix this? How can i make it work with yarn-client mode with python 3.6?

```
spark2-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf 'spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/apps/anaconda/4.3.1/3/bin/python3.6' --conf 'spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/apps/anaconda/4.3.1/3/bin/python3.6'  --queue=queue-name --py-files custom-python-code.zip file.py
```

Comment: how do you check which version of python your `spark-submit` is using?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/apps/anaconda/4.3.1/3/bin/python3.6
```

use

```
spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/apps/anaconda/4.3.1/3/bin/python3.6
```

The former one is applicable only in the cluster mode.

Comment: That didn't work either. Still getting Python 2.6.6.

Comment: It worked with below command:
`export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/apps/anaconda/4.3.1/3/bin/python3.6`